# Create android spinner dynamically in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin, android-spinner

I am creating a simple application to get familiar with Xamarin. I want to create and populate a spinner and display its options dynamically. I have seen the documentation [here](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/spinner) but it is not created programmatically. Any help will be appreciated

```
var levels = new List<String>() { "Easy", "Medium", "Hard", "Multiplayer" };
var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, levels);
                    adapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
var spinner = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spnrGameLevel);
spinner.Adapter = adapter;

spinner.ItemSelected += (sender, e) =>
{
    var s = sender as Spinner;
    Toast.MakeText(this, "My favorite is " + s.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position), ToastLength.Short).Show();
};
```

My axml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Choose your game level" />
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spnrGameLevel" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To dynamically create items for `Spinner`, you need to have an [adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter.html).

The simplest adapter would be [`ArrayAdapter<T>`](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T:Android.Widget.ArrayAdapter%3CT%3E).

Here is the example.

```
var items = new List<string>() {"one", "two", "three"};
var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, items);
```

After setting up the `adapter`, find the `Spinner` in your view and set `adapter` to it.

```
var spinner = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinner);
spinner.Adapter = adapter;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried the same, but getting an exception while tried this. Object Reference not set to an instance of an object. I have updated the my question with code

Comment: @Anand Which statement caused the exception?

Comment: Exception occurs in `spinner.Adapter = adapter;`

Comment: @Anand Did you forget to instantiate the view contains the `spinner`?

Comment: No, I have instantiated the view

Comment: @Anand It's weird. I tried the same thing, just adding `SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);` in `OnCreate` method. And it works.

Comment: It's because spinner is not invoked ,,, you should put SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main); before using var spinner = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinner);